# R: A Function to Return two values Separated with a Long Vertical Line (|)

Tags: r

I want a function to return two values separated with a long vertical line (|)

```
FUN1 <- function(x) {
  attach(x)
  return(min(x2))
}

FUN2 <- function(x) {
  attach(x)
  return(x1[which.min(x2)])
}


set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(
  x1 = 1:10,
  x2 = rnorm(10)
)
FUN1(x)
FUN2(x)
```

I want to combine the two functions (`FUN1` and `FUN2`) into one with a result like this:

> -0.8356286|3

Comment: You should rather avoid the use of `attach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a 3rd function to combine output from `FUN1` and `FUN2`.

```
FUN1 <- function(x) {
  return(with(x, min(x2)))
}

FUN2 <- function(x) {
  return(with(x, x1[which.min(x2)]))
}

FUN3 <- function(x) {
  paste(round(FUN1(x), 3), FUN2(x), sep = '|')
}

FUN3(x)
#[1] "-0.836|3"
```

---

If you want to eliminate `FUN1` and `FUN2` completely.

```
FUN3 <- function(x) {
  with(x, paste(round(min(x2), 3), x1[which.min(x2)], sep = '|'))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
  filter(x2 == min(x2)) %>% 
  mutate(out = paste0(round(x2,7),"|",x1)) %>% 
  pull(out)

"-0,8356286|3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sprintf` as well as `signif` to avoid `0.000`'s,

```
do.call(sprintf, c('%s|%s', rev(signif(x[which.min(x$x2), ], 3))))
# [1] "-0.836|3"
```

or if your open to a slightly different format:

```
toString(rev(signif(x[which.min(x$x2), ], 3)))
# [1] "-0.836, 3"
```